# iTunes automatically stops/starts music whenever I start/stop Skype call

Tags: itunes, music, skype

Couldn't find any similar questions.

So I like that my iTunes music automatically pauses when I accept a Skype call, but usually during a Skype call I turn up the volume. Then when my Skype call ends, my music comes back, but blasted in my ears. Is there a setting I should know of to prevent this?

I am on a Mac Air running Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iTunes has a separate volume control that seems to run independently of the master volume control. It's in the top-left corner, press <kbd>⌘↑</kbd> or <kbd>⌘↓</kbd> in iTunes to adjust.

Yours may be too low relative to the master volume.

Skype too has a separate volume control. In the Skype app press <kbd>⌥⌘↑</kbd> and <kbd>⌥⌘↓</kbd> to adjust call output volume only.

Comment: ah, thank you! this seems useful. although i'm pretty sure there are some settings involved that can be set.